# How to make join in Apex oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sum, oracle-apex

Halloooooo

please help me for my assignment

i have 2 table  :

-Nasabah (id,name,addres).

-Transaksi_Nasabah (id,nominal,date,kategori,id_nasabah)

in kategori have 2 value (Deposit and Withdrawal)

```
ID  NOMINAL DATE        KATEGORI    ID_NASABAH
3   100000  03/02/2020  Deposit       3
5   100000  03/02/2020  Deposit       5
4   100000  03/02/2020  Deposit       4
7   10000   03/09/2020  Deposit       1
13  50000   03/11/2020  Withdtawal    2
14  25000   03/16/2020  Deposit       3
......................................... etc
```

and i must make

```
 total deposit       760000
 total withdrawal    130000
 Saldo (Deposit-WD)  630000
 MAX Deposit         100000
 Min Deposit         5000
 Max Withdrawal      50000
 Min Withdrawal      10000
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you want it, it looks like a series of `UNION`ed `select` statements, e.g.

```
SQL> with test (nominal, kategori) as
  2    (select 100, 'Deposit'    from dual union all
  3     select 200, 'Deposit'    from dual union all
  4     select  50, 'Withdrawal' from dual union all
  5     select  30, 'Withdrawal' from dual
  6    )
  7  select 'total deposit' what  , sum(nominal) result from test where kategori = 'Deposit'
  8  union all
  9  select 'total withdrawal'    , sum(nominal) from test where kategori = 'Withdrawal'
 10  union all
 11  select 'saldo (deposit - wd)', sum(case when kategori = 'Deposit' then nominal
 12                                          when kategori = 'Withdrawal' then -nominal
 13                                     end
 14                                    )
 15    from test
 16  union all
 17  select 'max deposit'         , max(nominal) from test where kategori = 'Deposit';

WHAT                     RESULT
-------------------- ----------
total deposit               300
total withdrawal             80
saldo (deposit - wd)        220
max deposit                 200

SQL>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer and added "live example" which shows how to do that. SALDO begins at line 11.